# How to rename my folder and any of its subfolders into lowercase using command prompt in Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, rename, batch-rename

I have many folders and subfolders. They have random uppercase or lowercase letters in their names. I'd like to rename all of them into lowercase version.

I see many answer here about renaming files but not folders. How'd I do it using command prompt?

Comment: Maybe you could update your question and show us what you've already tried and where you got stuck?

Comment: I am not familiar with command prompt code.

Comment: If you're not familiar with command prompt code (yet), why do you want a solution that uses that?

Comment: why not? I know command prompt can do something to folder or file access etc. But, I do not know how to rename folders

Comment: the `rename` command can  rename both files and directories

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's much easier to use PowerShell instead of the legacy cmd

```powershell
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.ToLower() } -WhatIf
```

Shorter version

```powershell
ls -Di -R | ren -Ne { $_.Name.ToLower() } -wi
```

It'll rename all subfolders of the current folder to lowercase

After confirming the new names are correct then remove `-WhatIf` / `-wi` to do real renaming

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried one of those batch renamer software? Some are free and very easy to use, it could be easier than trying to do it with the windows cmd. Here's one free if you want to give it a try;
https://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/

Comment: I haven't installed it. but from the website description it is not rename folders,is it?

Comment: If you scroll down to the "Basic Features" section they say it can rename folder, and from what I remember when I used it years ago I'm pretty sure I did just that :)

Comment: If you uncheck everything but the case section(4), set it to lower case and check only folder in filter (12) I think you'll get exactly what you want

Comment: a folder is just a special file that contains other files. Anything that renames a file will also rename a folder